# Check if my Python has all required packages

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I have a `requirements.txt` file with a list of packages that are required for my virtual environment. Is it possible to find out whether all the packages mentioned in the file are present. If some packages are missing, how to find out which are the missing packages?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

An up-to-date and improved way to do this is via `distutils.text_file.TextFile`. See Acumenus' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45474387/240950) below for details.

**ORIGINAL**:

The pythonic way of doing it is via the `pkg_resources` [API](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#api-reference). The requirements are written in a format understood by setuptools. E.g:

```
Werkzeug>=0.6.1
Flask
Django>=1.3
```

The example code:

```
import pkg_resources
from pkg_resources import DistributionNotFound, VersionConflict

# dependencies can be any iterable with strings, 
# e.g. file line-by-line iterator
dependencies = [
  'Werkzeug>=0.6.1',
  'Flask>=0.9',
]

# here, if a dependency is not met, a DistributionNotFound or VersionConflict
# exception is thrown. 
pkg_resources.require(dependencies)
```

Comment: As a bonus, this automatically recursively detects conflicting version requirements -- these would be unsatisfiable.

Comment: Loop over the require call with a try: except pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound wrapping the call. Then on exception you print. This way it'll tell you all missing dependencies and not die on the first missing one found.

Comment: The update links to Asclepius's answer. However, it doesn't use `distutils.text_file.TextFile` like the text of this answer indicates.

Comment: It seems that `pkg_resources.require` is deprecated now... (I'm looking for the non-deprecated version...)

Answer (score 28):

Based on the [answer by Zaur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16298328/), assuming you indeed use a  requirements file, you may want a unit test, perhaps in `tests/test_requirements.py`, that confirms the availability of packages.

Moreover, this approach uses a [subtest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#distinguishing-test-iterations-using-subtests) to independently confirm each requirement. This is useful so that all failures are documented. Without subtests, only a single failure is documented.

```py
"""Test availability of required packages."""

import unittest
from pathlib import Path

import pkg_resources

_REQUIREMENTS_PATH = Path(__file__).parent.with_name("requirements.txt")


class TestRequirements(unittest.TestCase):
    """Test availability of required packages."""

    def test_requirements(self):
        """Test that each required package is available."""
        # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45474387/
        requirements = pkg_resources.parse_requirements(_REQUIREMENTS_PATH.open())
        for requirement in requirements:
            requirement = str(requirement)
            with self.subTest(requirement=requirement):
                pkg_resources.require(requirement)
```

Comment: This is truly a great idea!

Comment: Updated the accepted answer with a reference to your answer.

Comment: @R.Ilma With subtests you can know exactly the full subset of requirements that failed, so it's frequently useful while testing. Without subtests, you only know the first failure.

Comment: When I run the test I get the error `AttributeError: module 'distutils' has no attribute 'text_file'` when I did check the `distutils` source code I didn't find `text_file`, I'm using Python 3.6.9

Comment: @Acumenus, thank you for your prompt reply, I just added [some details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60475507/4488332) with the solution I found. (sorry I did a mistake in the Python version, it's 3.6.9)

Comment: Instead of `distutils.text_file.TextFile`, one could use [_setuptools_ own `pkg_resources.parse_requirements`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#requirements-parsing), like in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59971236/11138259

Comment: @sinoroc Actually this answer used to use `pkg_resources.parse_requirements` as you can confirm in its edit history. I had to stop using it because its API was extremely wonky and used to keep breaking all the time. Now I have edited the answer again to go back to using it as per your suggestion.

Comment: I see, I think I'd already been told before that for a while that API was somewhat untrustworthy, don't remember the exact details anymore. Anyway, I appreciate when people make the effort to keep their answers up-to-date, thanks.

Comment: is it possible to install the missing packages inside the for ?

Comment: @Juan-Kabbali Even if it's possible, it's very non-standard. The packages are supposed to be managed by a package manager, e.g. pip, poetry, conda, etc., so the same package would have to be run. The standard workflow, however, is to first install the defined list of packages (as per the usage instructions of the chosen package manager), and only then run the unit tests.

Comment: One thing this doesn't handle are referenced files (e.g. `-r requirements.txt` in a requirements-dev.txt file). This produces a parse error and requires a little more work to make it work.

Comment: @SamBull Noted, but then I have littler reason to reference `requirements.txt` in `requirements-dev.txt` because I can use `pip install -U -r ./requirements.txt -r ./requirements-dev.txt` to install both via a single command.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer which helped me a lot. While trying to understand the code, I saw that `pkg_resources` has become deprecated according to the [setuptools documentation](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html) and must be replaced by `importlib`, however I can't find any function equivalent to parse_requirements in this library, any ideas?

Answer (score 22):

You can run `pip freeze` to see what you have installed and compare it to your `requirements.txt` file.

If you want to install missing modules you can run `pip install -r requirements.txt` and that will install any missing modules and tell you at the end which ones were missing and installed.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `-r` option from `pip freeze` that verifies that. It generates a `WARNING` log for packages that are not installed. One appropriated verbose mode should be selected in order the `WARNING` message to be shown. For example:

```
$ pip -vvv freeze -r requirements.txt | grep "not installed"

WARNING: Requirement file [requirements.txt] contains six==1.15.0, but package 'six' is not installed
```

Comment: This works, but not for the obvious reason (at least for pip version 23.0.1). pip outputs to stdout a series of messages, none of which match `not installed`, so all of the output sent to stdout is discarded. In addition pip outputs to stderr the Warning messages. So a more efficient thing to use is `pip freeze -r requirements.txt > /dev/null`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a one-liner based on Zaur Nasibov's answer for if you don't care to know *which* packages are not installed:

```sh
python3 -c "import pkg_resources; pkg_resources.require(open('requirements.txt',mode='r'))" &>/dev/null
```

Whether the command finishes successfully can then be used to do a pip install.

As an equivalent to Ruby's `bundle check || bundle install`, we're doing:

```sh
python3 -c "import pkg_resources; pkg_resources.require(open('requirements.txt',mode='r'))" &>/dev/null || pip3 install --ignore-installed -r requirements.txt
```

I realise this is not addressing the exact question, but this page comes up first when Googling for that. And anyway, you'd only really be wanting to know what the missing dependencies are in order to then satisfy them.

We can't just use `pip3 check` for this, since it does not look at the `requirements.txt`

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in doing this from the command line, `pip-missing-reqs` will list missing packages. Example:

```
$ pip-missing-reqs directory
Missing requirements:
directory/exceptions.py:11 dist=grpcio module=grpc
```

(`pip check` and `pipdeptree --warn fail` only audit installed packages for compatibility with each other, without checking `requirements.txt`.)

Comment: `pip check` does not verify the packages in a requirements file are installed. `pip check` verifies that already installed packages have compatible/non-broken dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Running

```
pip freeze -r requirements.txt
```

it will compare installed ones to the requirements file and warn you which ones are not

Answer (score 1):

[Answer by Asclepius](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45474387/11758622) revisited to avoid using the pkg_resources library which is now deprecated. I don't have much experience with pip, so it probably has errors in this code, but it gave very similar results to the original answer.

```py
"""Test availability of required packages."""

import unittest
from pathlib import Path

from pip._internal.req.req_file import parse_requirements
from pip._internal.req.constructors import install_req_from_parsed_requirement
from pip._internal.network.session import PipSession
from pip._internal.exceptions import DistributionNotFound

_REQUIREMENTS_PATH = Path(__file__).parent.with_name("requirements.txt")

class TestRequirements(unittest.TestCase):
    """Test availability of required packages."""

    def test_requirements(self):
        """Test that each required package is available."""
        # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45474387/
        session = PipSession()
        requirements = parse_requirements(str(_REQUIREMENTS_PATH), session)
        for requirement in requirements:
            req_to_install = install_req_from_parsed_requirement(requirement)
            req_to_install.check_if_exists(use_user_site=False)
            with self.subTest(req_to_install=str(req_to_install)):
                if not req_to_install.satisfied_by:
                    raise DistributionNotFound()
```

Comment: Implementation: https://github.com/trtb/python_toolbox/blob/main/src/environment_check.py

Answer (score 0):

In addition to check whether modules listed in `requirements.txt` are installed, you may want to check whether all used modules by your project are indeed listed in the `requirements.txt` file.

If you are using flake8 for style-checking, you can add [flake8-requirements](https://pypi.org/project/flake8-requirements/) plugin for flake8. It will automatically check whether imported modules are available in `setup.py`, `requirements.txt` or `pyproject.toml` file. Additionally, for custom modules you can add custom configuration with known-modules (in order to prevent flake8 warnings). For more configuration options, see flake8-requirements project's description.