# Programmatically check if Python dependencies are satisfied

Tags: python, dependencies, pip

I'd like to programmatically run `pip` and determine whether the current virtualenv environment complies with a specified `requirements.txt` file. I'm not fussed about running `pip` or anything, but I thought since it can read `requirements.txt`-like files, it would be a good start.

However, I haven't even found a way of effectively running `pip` from the command line. `pip install -r requirements.txt --no-install` was suggested somewhere, but it downloads each package and even if this wasn't a problem, I am unsure of how to interpret its output as to whether or not all dependencies are satisfied.

Comment: See this relevant thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294819/how-to-check-if-my-python-has-all-required-packages

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see this thread. Only the response `pkg_resources` seems to be useful, but I doubt that it'll work with things like `github` repositories as dependency in `requirements.txt`. I might need to resort to this approach, if this is the only option...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if my Python has all required packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294819/how-to-check-if-my-python-has-all-required-packages)

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-locally-installed-python-modules) post has a lot of good suggestions for getting a list of modules. You can use the below code to print out all missing modules:

```
from pkgutil import iter_modules
modules = set(x[1] for x in iter_modules())

with open('requirements.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        requirement = line.rstrip()
        if not requirement in modules:
            print requirement
```