# Proper way to parse requirements file after pip upgrade to pip 10.x.x?

Tags: python, pip

So today I did found out that with the release of `pip 10.x.x` the `req` package changed its directory and can now be found under `pip._internal.req`.

Since it is common practice to use the `parse_requirements` function in your `setup.py` to install all the dependencies out of a requirements file I now wonder if this practice should change since it is now lying under `_internal`?

Or what is actually best practice without using `parse_requirements`?

Comment: It may be a common practice, but I don't think it ever was a best practice. I've always done it the other way around and had `requirements.txt` reference `.` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference requirements.txt for the install\_requires kwarg in setuptools setup.py file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399534/reference-requirements-txt-for-the-install-requires-kwarg-in-setuptools-setup-py)

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2286#issuecomment-68285791

Comment: @DanielPryden I guessed so. How would that look like?

Comment: Thank you for your input. I found a code sample. https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/pc-nrfutil/pull/94/files

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First, I believe parsing `requirements.txt` to fill the list of dependencies in package metadata is not a good idea. The `requirements.txt` file and the list of "install dependencies" are two different concepts, they are not interchangeable. It should be the other way around, the list of dependencies in package metadata should be considered as some kind of source of truth, and files such as `requirements.txt` should be generated from there. For example with a tool such as [*`pip-compile`*](https://pypi.org/project/pip-tools/). See the notes at the bottom of this answer.

But everyone has different needs, that lead to different workflows. So with that said... There are 3 possibilities to handle this, depending on where you want your project's package metadata to be written: *`pyproject.toml`*, *`setup.cfg`*, or *`setup.py`*.

---

***Words of caution!***

If you insist on having the list of dependencies in package metadata be read from a `requirements.txt` file then make sure that this `requirements.txt` file is included in the "source distribution" (*sdist*) otherwise build (to *wheel*) and subsequent installation will fail, for obvious reasons.

These techniques will work only for simple `requirements.txt` files. See [*Requirements parsing* in the documentation page for `pkg_resources`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#requirements-parsing) to get details about what is handled. In short, each line should be a valid [*PEP 508* requirement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/). [Notations that are really specific to *pip*](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format) are not supported and it will cause a failure.

---

***`pyproject.toml`***

```
[project]
# ...
dynamic = ["dependencies"]

[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
# ...
dependencies = requirements.txt
```

---

***`setup.cfg`***

Since setuptools version 62.6 it is possible to write something like this in `setup.cfg`:

```
[options]
install_requires = file: requirements.txt
```

---

***`setup.py`***

It is possible to parse a relatively simple `requirements.txt` file from a *setuptools* `setup.py` script without *pip*. The *setuptools* project already contains necessary tools in its *top level* package `pkg_resources`.

It could more or less look like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pathlib

import pkg_resources
import setuptools

with pathlib.Path('requirements.txt').open() as requirements_txt:
    install_requires = [
        str(requirement)
        for requirement
        in pkg_resources.parse_requirements(requirements_txt)
    ]

setuptools.setup(
    install_requires=install_requires,
)
```

---

***Notes***:

- https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1951#issuecomment-1431345869
- https://caremad.io/posts/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/
- https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/history.html#v62-6-0
- See also this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59971469

Comment: This doesn't handle complex entries like `-r extra_req.txt`. The options importing from pip do solve these cases, but they have other problems.

Comment: Yes, it is true. The answer states "_parse a relatively simple `requirements.txt` file_" on purpose, it could be more explicit about it.

Comment: Note that while the "Requirements parsing" link doesn't explicitly say, it does appear to handle comments in the requirements.txt file.

Comment: more or less..?

Comment: @jtlz2 "more or less" because the `setup.py` needs to be adapted to the rest of the project's needs, and most likely it will not be enough to just copy-paste this example into your own project, some adjustments are probably need.

Comment: Use of pkg_resources is discouraged in favor of importlib.resources, importlib.metadata. Source:
https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html

Comment: @GeorgiosSyngouroglou From my point of view, this note is irrelevant here for now. The features of `pkg_resources` we use here is not available in `importlib` and will most likely stay in `pkg_resources` for the foreseeable future. Anyway this can be done directly in `setup.cfg` and `pyproject.toml` now without needing a `setup.py` that imports `pkg_resources`.

Answer (score 11):

The [solution of Scrotch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57191701/4292396) only works until `pip 19.0.3`, in the `pip >= 20` versions the PipSession module was refactored. Here is a solution for the imports that works for all `pip` versions:

```
try:
    # pip >=20
    from pip._internal.network.session import PipSession
    from pip._internal.req import parse_requirements
except ImportError:
    try:
        # 10.0.0 <= pip <= 19.3.1
        from pip._internal.download import PipSession
        from pip._internal.req import parse_requirements
    except ImportError:
        # pip <= 9.0.3
        from pip.download import PipSession
        from pip.req import parse_requirements
```

Comment: The solution of @sinoroc is clean. However, if using tools like `pip-tools` to create your `requirements.txt` file, items such as `--trusted-host` may be introduced in the `requirements.txt` file, which the `pkg_resources` package fails to parse.

Comment: Haven't tested it, but I have no doubt you're right. When working with tools such as _pip-tools_, then I don't see the point of parsing `requirements.txt` from within `setup.py`, the tools should read `setup.py` or `setup.cfg` to generate `requirements.txt`, not the the other way around. But I guess everyone has their own needs for different workflows.

Comment: This is less useful than what it looks like. Presumably you want to actually use it, like `[r.requirement for r in parse_requirements(filename, session=PipSession())]`. That works for pip >=20, but does not work for 9.0.3. Does anyone have a cross-version compatible way of getting the lines back out of this? In any form.

Comment: Just use pkg_resources

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT: modified to support `pip>= 19.0.3`**

I don't agree with the accepted answer. The `setup.py` file can get ugly real fast if you have a large project with a lot of dependencies. It is always good practice to keep your requirements in a separate `.txt` file. I would do something like this -

```
try:
    # pip >=20
    from pip._internal.network.session import PipSession
    from pip._internal.req import parse_requirements
except ImportError:
    try:
        # 10.0.0 <= pip <= 19.3.1
        from pip._internal.download import PipSession
        from pip._internal.req import parse_requirements
    except ImportError:
        # pip <= 9.0.3
        from pip.download import PipSession
        from pip.req import parse_requirements

requirements = parse_requirements(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'requirements.txt'), session=PipSession())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(
        ...
        install_requires=[str(requirement.requirement) for requirement in requirements],
        ...
    )
```

Throw in all your requirements in `requirements.txt` under project root directory.

Comment: I mean how you load the list of packages into your setup.py is a complete other topic. You can import that from another file that lives somewhere else. But i still think it is wrong to be dependend on the pip library in your own application. If you dont want to have the package list inside your setup.py put it in any other file put it into a constant and import that into your setup.py

Answer (score 5):

What I figured out the right way to do is adding the dependencies in the setup.py like:

```
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [
    'boto3==1.7.33'
]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(
        ...
        install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
        ...
    )
```

and just have a `.` in your `requirements.txt`. It will then automatically install all packages from the `setup.py` if you install from the file.

Answer (score 0):

@sinoroc is correct that you generally do not want to populate your setup() function using your requirements.txt. They are for different things: requirements.txt produces a maximal, reproducible environment with hard versions to aid in deployments, help other developers etc.. Setup dependencies are a minimal, permissive list to allow users to install things.

However, sometimes you want to install an application using pip, or collaborators insist on using the requirements file, so I wrote a package which helps you do this: https://pypi.org/project/extreqs/

Answer (score -6):

```
with open("requirements.txt") as f:
    dependencies = [line for line in f if "==" in line]

setup(
    install_requires=dependencies
)
```

Comment: There's a lot more to `requirements.txt` syntax than just `==`.

Comment: See: https://jmchilton-galaxy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pkg_resources.html#parse_requirements for some of the bases you would need to cover if you rolled your own. But also, you can just use pkg_resources