# Use python pip install git+git to setup local Python environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, python-2.7, pip

I understand that it is possible to install packages from git and pip using the command below.

> pip install git+git://github.com/author/package.git@master

So basically what this new command should do is that,

It should install all the packages necessary in my local just by using names or more precisely without me uploading the full package to git, only their names.

So Basically, I am trying to replicate this command with git.

> pip install -r requirements.txt

Is this even possible? Has anyone done it?

Examples: Requirements.txt contain :

```
pandas==1.0.4 
matplotlib==3.2.1 
numpy=1.18.5
```

So something in the git with setup.py along the lines of it to install that package, if possible.

```
import pip 

    with open('requirements.txt','r') as fh:   
      for line in fh.readlines():
        pip install line
```

Comment: No, that's the same old question I asked which no one minded. :(

Comment: Copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62312547/create-python-package-installer-from-git-without-uploading-actual-package

Comment: That means you have to clarify or extend it, not post it again.

Comment: @KlausD. It's removed. It can now stay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not sure I fully understand, what is the goal here...

Maybe you want to somehow have the `requirements.txt` file in a git repository and have it installed with *pip*. The goal being to have the requirements version controlled.

I believe you could achieve something to that effect with some kind of fake Python package that has no code, only dependencies.

Place the following 2 files in a `MyDependencies` git repository:

`setup.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pathlib

import pkg_resources
import setuptools

with pathlib.Path('requirements.txt').open() as requirements_txt:
    install_requires = [
        str(requirement)
        for requirement
        in pkg_resources.parse_requirements(requirements_txt)
    ]

setuptools.setup(
    name='MyDependencies',
    version='0.0.0',
    install_requires=install_requires,
)
```

`requirements.txt`

```
pandas==1.0.4 
matplotlib==3.2.1 
numpy=1.18.5
```

Then the dependencies can be installed like so:

```
path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip install --upgrade git+git://github.com/username/MyDependencies.git@master
```

If I am not mistaken, this should do the trick.

**References**:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59971236/11138259

Comment: Thanks @sinoroc. This is exactly what I needed and did the trick.