# How can I check that the installed packages match Pipfile.lock using pipenv?

Tags: python, pipenv, pipfile

In my tests, I would like to run a command to make sure that the installed packages in my virtual environment match the packages found in `Pipfile.lock`.

Is there a command like this?

```
pipenv checkifinstalled || exit 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be reduced down to these two steps:

1. Convert `Pipfile.lock` into a `requirements.txt` file (in the format generated by `pip freeze`).

   - This is easily done by running `pipenv requirements` (or `pipenv requirements --dev`). (Note that this command is supported in pipenv >= 2022.4.8)
2. Check that the installed packages match the generated `requirements.txt` file.

   - Solutions to this are found under this question: [Check if my Python has all required packages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16294819/247696)

### Implementation:

Here is how I put it all together in a test:

```py
import pkg_resources
import subprocess
import unittest

class DependencyChecks(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_requirements_installed(self):
        requirements_lines = subprocess.check_output(["pipenv", "requirements", "--dev"], text=True).splitlines()
        req_lines = [line for line in requirements_lines if not line.startswith("-i ")]
        requirements = pkg_resources.parse_requirements(req_lines)
        for requirement in requirements:
            req = str(requirement)
            with self.subTest(requirement=req):
                pkg_resources.require(req)
```