# Interrogate Python package dependencies without using network

Tags: python, pip

How can I query Python's 'pip' to answer the question "is this install specification already satisfied", without any network requests?

To allow the build system to work offline, I want to interrogate the Python environment for *whether* anything would need to be installed to satisfy dependencies, and not actually make any network requests to do so.

The dependencies are declared using the 'pyproject.toml' file (and so, suggestions to [compare with a 'requirements.txt' file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294819/check-if-my-python-has-all-required-packages) don't apply; there is no such file).

```ini
[project]
name = "lorem"
dependencies = [
    "setuptools >= 62.4.0",
    "packaging",
    "dolor >= 0.10",
    ]

[project.optional-dependencies]
static-analysis = [
    "pycodestyle ~= 2.11",
    "pydocstyle ~= 6.3",
    ]
test = [
    "lorem[static-analysis]",
    "testscenarios >= 0.4",
    "coverage",
    ]
devel = [
    "lorem[test]",
    "isort ~= 5.12",
    "twine",
    ]
```

It's also not enough merely to check the "runtime dependencies"; I need to check whether the dependencies specifically for the 'test' feature, are installed.

The installation of the dependency packages for the test suite is done with:

```bash
$ python3 -m pip install .[test]
Processing /home/bignose/Projects/foo
[… installs some packages, reports that others are already satisfied …]
```

(meaning: Install this package and all dependencies, including those needed for the optional "test" feature.)

But the test suite should be run without needing any network access; so I want to *interrogate* package dependencies without any network requests.

I'm imagining a "just tell me if this is already satisfied" option:

```bash
$ python3 -m pip install --no-index --fail-if-any-packages-need-to-be-installed .[test]
Processing /home/bignose/Projects/foo
[… reports that some packages are not installed, others are already satisfied …]

$ if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then python3 -m unittest ; else echo "Test dependencies not installed; aborting." ; fi
```

So, the `python3 -m pip …` command here is instructed not to contact the package index (`--no-index`); it is *only* to get a success-or-failure result, for determining whether to run the test suite or abort now.

There is no such `--fail-if-any-packages-need-to-be-installed` option, but 'pip' obviously does know this information; it's all derived from inspecting what packages are installed locally, and the set of dependencies.

So how can I use 'pip' to do this?

Comment: I suppose you could temporarily point `pip` to a local index (maybe even one which doesn't exist?) and take it from there ...?

Comment: Tangentially, [Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern); also `if [ ! $? ]` is always true; it checks whether `$?` is not the empty string, which of course it cannot be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if my Python has all required packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294819/check-if-my-python-has-all-required-packages)